# md-highlight-text not highlighting the search text properly in Angular Js and Angular Material

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I've developed a project with angularjs and designed it with angular material. When I used md-autocomplete in my project, I faced a problem with highlight text. The highlight text not show properly. I tried to modified but failed. I copy the md-autocomplete code form angular material official website and modified them. My code is

```
 <div layout="row">
                <div flex="50">
                    <md-autocomplete flex required
                                     md-input-name="autocompleteField"
                                     md-input-minlength="2"
                                     md-input-maxlength="18"
                                     md-no-cache="noCache"
                                     md-selected-item="selectedItem"
                                     md-search-text="searchText"
                                     md-items="item in querySearch(searchText)"
                                     md-item-text="item.Name"
                                     md-require-match
                                     md-floating-label="Report To Name or Id">
                        <md-item-template>
                            <span md-highlight-text="searchText" md-highlight-flags="i">{{item.value}}-{{item.Name}}</span>
                        </md-item-template>
                        <div ng-messages="projectForm.autocompleteField.$error" ng-if="projectForm.autocompleteField.$touched">
                            <div ng-message="required">You <b>must</b> have a favorite state.</div>
                            <div ng-message="md-require-match">Please select an existing state.</div>
                            <div ng-message="minlength">Your entry is not long enough.</div>
                            <div ng-message="maxlength">Your entry is too long.</div>
                        </div>
                    </md-autocomplete>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And my AngularJs code is

```
$scope.querySearch=function(query) {
    var results = query ? $scope.Employees.filter($scope.createFilterFor(query)) : $scope.Employees;
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $timeout(function () { deferred.resolve(results); }, Math.random() * 1000, false);
    return deferred.promise;
}


$scope.loadEmployee = function () {
    return $scope.EmployeeList.map(function (employee) {
        return {
            value: employee.EmployeeId,
            display: employee.EmployeeName.toLowerCase(),
            Name:employee.EmployeeName
              }
    })
}

$scope.createFilterFor=function(query) {
    var lowercaseQuery = angular.lowercase(query);

    return function filterFn(employee) {
        return (employee.display.indexOf(lowercaseQuery) === 0 || employee.value.indexOf(lowercaseQuery)===0);
    };

}
```

The screenshot of this problem is as shown:

[[image: Screenshot]]

Please help me to solve this problem. I am waiting for your positive response.

Comment: remove angular tag - angular 2+

Comment: i think somehow your page have some css which is causing the highlighted text  style problem.

Answer (score 1):

If someone is struggling:

1. Trim all the possible result strings at the server-side:

   `'Name' => trim($name)`
2. Remove all blank spaces if any, inside this span

```html
<span md-highlight-text="searchText">{{item.Name}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @GauravSrivastava's comment. In Chrome, right-click the "highlighted" text, select "Inspect", then look in the "Styles" tab for any style that is not an Angular Material CSS file. I find the easiest way is to look to the right and scan for a file that is not apart of Angular Material. If you don't see any, select each parent element and check their styles. You most likely have a CSS style that you added or is in a different library that is overwriting one of the Angular Material styles.